# How to prevent a stuck shutter on my t5i

Tags: canon, shutter

I just had my shutter stick open, I was able to get it working again but how do I prevent it from happening in the future.

I was shooting with a 70-300mm lens on a 10 second exposure.

As an addendum any other maintenance  tips would be appreciated

Comment: How did you get it working again?

Comment: Took the lens off and hit the shutter and it worked

Comment: It shouldn't stick - ever. I recommend you contact Canon. (I assume no camera abuse on your part.)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably prevent this problem by making sure your *battery is fully charged*. Stuck shutter (or probably, stuck mirror) is a common symptom of low battery, especially when taking a long exposure or using the flash. By the end of the exposure the battery doesn't have enough juice left to close the shutter and flip the mirror back.  The other thing which challenges weak batteries is the self-timer. I've seen a situation where I could take a photo okay, but if I tried to use the self-timer, the camera would shut down with the mirror locked up.

Comment: I'll recharge the battery, however it will take a picture or show something when the lenses are off the camera when on black

Comment: Obviously, if the problem only occurs with one specific lens, the cause is likely something other than the battery.

Comment: It happened with all the lenses I am thinking its the mount tbh